# find nearest location in mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

Trying to following this sample below, find a nearest location in mongoDB

https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/geospatial-tutorial/

Create a simple class with getLongitudeand getLatitude

```
**

String json = "{'name':'" + rest.getName().toString() + "'," +
                    "'status':'" + rest.getStatus() + "'," +
                    "'code':'" + rest.getCode().toString() + "'," +
                    "'type':'" + rest.getCarType() + "'," +               
                    "'location': {'coordinates':" +
                    "[" +
                    Double.valueOf(rest.getLongitude()) + "," +
                    Double.valueOf(rest.getLatitude()) +
                    "]" +
                    "'type':'Point'}}" ;
```

**

How do search on this table.i tried but it is not working

```
BasicDBList coords= new BasicDBList();
        coords.add(Double.valueOf(searchDTO.getLatitude()));
        coords.add(Double.valueOf(searchDTO.getLongitude()));
        BasicDBObject loc2 = new BasicDBObject("type", "Point")
                .append("coordinates", (coords));

 Point currentLoc = new Point(new Position(searchDTO.getLongitude(),searchDTO.getLatitude()));

    FindIterable<Document> docs = collection.find(Filters.near("location",currentLoc,distanceInRad,distanceInMaxRad));
```

Comment: Share some more code. Type of each field to know which variant are you using.

Comment: What is the type of currentLoc and others in the same query.

Comment: currentLoc  is - user searching location

Comment: Thanks ,above code is working